# How to get caller object and field name in define_method with monkey patching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Following is my Module in which I am serializing an attribute in n_attribute method.
n_attrib_key is a method that is calling an `Object class` method `n_attrib` to create dynamic methods, 
The Object class is given below too.

What I actually want to do is pass the field from User to Module HashDemo, to serialize that field, once the field is serialized, now pass the keys in n_attrib_keys and create the dynamic methods of these keys in the Object class.

Once the methods are created, now called these methods by the attribute of object,

## Now the main problem that i am facing is

As i called the method and let bnow i am in that method. Now I want to store dynamic method's name ( as a "key" of hash) and "value" to the attribute of model just like that

## called

> @user.address.home = "value"

## what I want in the define_method

> @user.address = {home: "value"}

is there any way to get the caller object and attribute in the define_method, i.e who called this method, in this case ?

## Module

```
module HashDemo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def n_attributes(*args)
      args.each do |arg|
        serialize %(:#{arg})
      end
    end

    def n_attrib_keys(*names)
      Object.n_attrib(*names)
    end

  end
end
```

## Object class for monkey patching

```
class Object
  def n_attrib(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method("#{name}=") do |value|
        puts "setter"
        # @user.address = {"#{name}": value}
        # i.e. @model.field = {key: value}
      end

      define_method("#{name}") do
        puts "getter"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## My active recode class is this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name

  include HashDemo
  n_attributes :address
  n_attrib_keys :home, :location

  u = User.new
  u.address.home = value   # this will go to the setter define_method in the Object class
  u.address.home           # this will go to the getter define_method in Object class
end
```

Comment: @dre-hh this is the problem.

Comment: @Surya please refer any solution